# My Account and Shopping cart link not getting loaded in header for some pages in magento 2

Tags: magento2, header

There are few pages on my website where MyAccount and Shopping cart links are not getting loaded in my header.
Check header on this page https://wazoodle01.wsisites.net/index.php/knowledge-base/coupons-faq.html

While it gets loaded successfully on other pages. https://wazoodle01.wsisites.net/index.php/fabrics.html

In console I can see the error as theHeaderContainer.smartheader is not a function that is present in the header.phtml file

Can anyone help me to resolve this, please?

Comment: only issue on faq category list page

Comment: please upload layout of the faq category list page on question

Comment: yes...............

Comment: which faq module you use please share link

Comment: i am using knowledge based module from mirasvit. This issue is arising on all the pages developed from this extension

Comment: What i understand is the js are not getting loaded properly. what can be done for that?